# how to get FTDI FT4232 chip location information or serial number in windows with python?

Tags: pyserial, ftdi

I'm using a FTDI FT4232 chip to extend four COM ports on Windows 10.

These extended COM ports are linked to four different devices. So if I want to communicate with other devices via these COM ports, I need to know which ports to call.

I am coding with python, here is what I got with pyserial.

```
>python -m serial.tools.list_ports -v
COM3
    desc: USB Serial Port (COM3)
    hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 SER=5
COM4
    desc: USB Serial Port (COM4)
    hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 SER=5
COM5
    desc: USB Serial Port (COM5)
    hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 SER=5
COM6
    desc: USB Serial Port (COM6)
    hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 SER=5
4 ports found
```

But in Linux, pyserial can get location info which can be used to distinguish these four ports.

```
~$:python3 -m serial.tools.list_ports -v
/dev/ttyUSB0        
    desc: Quad RS232-HS
    hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-2.1:1.0
/dev/ttyUSB1        
    desc: Quad RS232-HS
    hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-2.1:1.1
/dev/ttyUSB2        
    desc: Quad RS232-HS
    hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-2.1:1.2
/dev/ttyUSB3        
    desc: Quad RS232-HS
    hwid: USB VID:PID=0403:6011 LOCATION=1-2.1:1.3
4 ports found
```

Anyone has any idea with this problem?

Temp solution:
Modify list_ports_windows.py as follow:

```
    elif szHardwareID_str.startswith('FTDIBUS'):
        m = re.search(r'VID_([0-9a-f]{4})\+PID_([0-9a-f]{4})(\+(\w*))&(\w*)&(\w*)&(\w*)&(\w*)?', szHardwareID_str, re.I)
        if m:
            info.vid = int(m.group(1), 16)
            info.pid = int(m.group(2), 16)
            if m.group(8):
                info.serial_number =  int(m.group(8),16)
        # USB location is hidden by FDTI driver :(
        info.hwid = info.usb_info()
```

Then you can call the port you want with vid+pid+serial_number.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a *location* field within the *ListPortInfo* returned by *serial.tools.list_ports.comports*. However it looks like the windows implementation of list_ports (list_ports_windows.py) seems to fail to correctly revive this information. I used the logging module to investigate this by adding the following line to my pyserial (installed on win10 64, python3.8). Adding

```
logging.debug("szHardwareID_str: %s" % szHardwareID_str) #added this lin
```

after

```
# stringify
szHardwareID_str = szHardwareID.value
```

yielded for me:

```
DEBUG:root:szHardwareID_str: ACPI\PNP0501\0
DEBUG:root:szHardwareID_str: FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6010+6&192CD50C&0&13&2\0000
DEBUG:root:szHardwareID_str: FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6010+6&192CD50C&0&13&1\0000
```

So on can see that the location is actually within this string but the later string analysis fails to correctly extract this information.I.E the implemented search does not match the locationID:

```
m = re.search(r'VID_([0-9a-f]{4})(&PID_([0-9a-f]{4}))?(&MI_(\d{2}))?(\\(\w+))?', szHardwareID_str, re.I)
```

Long story short: To the best of my knowledge you either modify pyserial (locally or globally by creating a patch+pull request) or you manually "extract" the information using the pyserial.tools.list_ports module. For example something like:

```
import ctypes
import serial
import logging

import serial.tools.list_ports_windows as lp

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

################copied from list_ports_windows.py
GUIDs = (lp.GUID * 8)()  # so far only seen one used, so hope 8 are enough...
guids_size = lp.DWORD()
if not lp.SetupDiClassGuidsFromName(
        "Ports",
        GUIDs,
        ctypes.sizeof(GUIDs),
        ctypes.byref(guids_size)):
    raise ctypes.WinError()

# repeat for all possible GUIDs
for index in range(guids_size.value):
    bInterfaceNumber = None
    g_hdi = lp.SetupDiGetClassDevs(
        ctypes.byref(GUIDs[index]),
        None,
        lp.NULL,
        lp.DIGCF_PRESENT)  # was DIGCF_PRESENT|DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE which misses CDC ports

    devinfo = lp.SP_DEVINFO_DATA()
    devinfo.cbSize = ctypes.sizeof(devinfo)
    index = 0
    while lp.SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo(g_hdi, index, ctypes.byref(devinfo)):
        index += 1

        # get the real com port name
        hkey = lp.SetupDiOpenDevRegKey(
            g_hdi,
            ctypes.byref(devinfo),
            lp.DICS_FLAG_GLOBAL,
            0,
            lp.DIREG_DEV,  # DIREG_DRV for SW info
            lp.KEY_READ)
        port_name_buffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(250)
        port_name_length = lp.ULONG(ctypes.sizeof(port_name_buffer))
        lp.RegQueryValueEx(
            hkey,
            "PortName",
            None,
            None,
            ctypes.byref(port_name_buffer),
            ctypes.byref(port_name_length))
        lp.RegCloseKey(hkey)

        # unfortunately does this method also include parallel ports.
        # we could check for names starting with COM or just exclude LPT
        # and hope that other "unknown" names are serial ports...
        if port_name_buffer.value.startswith('LPT'):
            continue

        # hardware ID
        szHardwareID = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(250)
        # try to get ID that includes serial number
        if not lp.SetupDiGetDeviceInstanceId(
                g_hdi,
                ctypes.byref(devinfo),
                #~ ctypes.byref(szHardwareID),
                szHardwareID,
                ctypes.sizeof(szHardwareID) - 1,
                None):
            # fall back to more generic hardware ID if that would fail
            if not lp.SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(
                    g_hdi,
                    ctypes.byref(devinfo),
                    lp.SPDRP_HARDWAREID,
                    None,
                    ctypes.byref(szHardwareID),
                    ctypes.sizeof(szHardwareID) - 1,
                    None):
                # Ignore ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER
                if ctypes.GetLastError() != lp.ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER:
                    raise ctypes.WinError()
        # stringify
        szHardwareID_str = szHardwareID.value

        print(szHardwareID_str)
```

However a general solution (i.e. patch) would be the best way IMHO. Maybe you could just open an ISSUE at the official pyserial repos.

Comment: Thank you, Christian. You have point a direction for me to find a solution.I dig into the code of list_port_windows.py and found that the FTDI chips were processed separately. And the author has pointed it clearly the location info was hidden by FTDI. So I modified the way the serial number parsed. I got the last character of hardware info from hardware id string and use it as serial number.